# Calculation of the Distance Matrix in the K-Means Algorithm in MATLAB

Tags: performance, mathematics, machine-learning, matlab, clustering

*Purpose of the code* :

To assign the corresponding label of the centroids to the points which are close to it. Below is a graphical (2D) example.

[image]

---

> Variable **X** is a matrix, rows represent the points, columns collectively represent the coordinates
>
> **idx** is the list of centroids assigned to every example

Inefficient MATLAB code to find and assign nearest Centroids

```
sd2=size(X,2);
t2=[];
for a=1:K
    t1=[];
    for b=1:sd2
        temp=(X(:,b)-centroids(a,b)).^2;
        t1=[t1 temp];
    end
    dmat=sum(t1,2);
    t2=[t2 dmat];
end
[~,idx]=min(t2,[],2);
```

supposedly faster MATLAB code which worked on a small dataset:

```
[~,idx]=min(sum(((repmat(X,1,1,K)-reshape(centroids,1,n,K)).^2),2),[],3);
```

**My Question:**

Is my second implementation correct? If yes, why doesn't it work on a **300 x 2** matrix **X** , in the sense that the final array **idx** produced is not correct. If no, where is the problem (because I tested it with a small sample code just to be sure that I am finding (x-x<sub>1</sub>)<sup>2</sup>+ (y-y<sub>1</sub>)<sup>2</sup> correctly).

***speculation:***

MATLAB is erroneous because of a multidimensional matrix.

Comment: Could you share the data in a `MAT` or `CSV` file? I will give a reference code for it.

Comment: @Royi https://gofile.io/d/NM9A9q ignore the .txt I tried to add. I was opening in it my computer on notepad

Comment: Posted the solution. Enjoy...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Your Distance Matrix Calculation

You wrote the code (I summarize it for the Distance Matrix):

```
K = 3;
n = size(mX, 1);
d = size(mX, 2); %<! Number of dimensions per sample
mC = mX(randperm(n, K), :);

% mD = repmat(mX, 1, 1, K) - reshape(mC, 1, n, K); %<! Your code, Will fail because of reshape
mD = sum((reshape(mX, n, 1, d) - reshape(mC.', 1, K, d)) .^ 2, 3); %<! Correctly with no `repmat()`
```

The reason it won't work is the reshaping operation you're doing.
The number of elements in `mC` is `K x d` while your `reshape()` should keep the number of elements.

In the following I gave you a code snippet how to calculate the matrix `mD` efficiently.

### K-Means

To calculate the distance you shouldn't use `repmat()` which will allocate new memory.
To calculate the *Distance Matrix* with the 3rd dimension and broadcasting you should do something like:

```
mD = sum((reshape(mA, numVarA, 1, varDim) - reshape(mB.', 1, numVarB, varDim)) .^ 2, 3);
```

But a faster way would be:

```
mD = sum(mA .^ 2).' - (2 * mA.' * mB) + sum(mB .^ 2);
```

Which utilizes the fast the Matrix Multiplication is probably the most optimized algorithm and that:

$$ {\left\| \boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{y} \right\|}_{2}^{2} = \boldsymbol{x}^{T} \boldsymbol{x} - 2 \boldsymbol{x}^{T} \boldsymbol{y} + \boldsymbol{y}^{T} \boldsymbol{y} $$

For you to have a reference of K-Means algorithm with support for any Distance Function I created a function and ran it on your data:

[image]

It will converge very fast for that data:

[image]

I also created a small benchmark for various algorithm to compute the Euclidean Squared Distance Matrix.
The first test was between 3 approaches to calculate the distance between a single set of vectors (For example given by a single matrix):

[image]

The second test I compared 2 Row / Column variations of the algorithm above:

[image]

The Row / Column variations means I test the algorithm in 2 cases:

1. Row Variation - Each data sample is a row in the data matrix (Like your data).
2. Column Variation - Each data sample is a column in the data matrix (In MATLAB it means the sample is contiguous in memory).

As can be seen, it is always better to have data in the column variation.

**Remark**: Pay attention that the *Squared Euclidean Distance* doesn't obey the [Triangle Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) which is a requirement for a [Metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)). It is used for computational efficiency as it doesn't change the *K-Means* algorithm results compared to Euclidean Distance (The L<sub>2</sub> Norm based distance).

The MATLAB Code is accessible in my [StackExchange Code Review Q254186 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes/tree/master/CodeReview/Q254186).

**Remark**: The K-Means algorithm, as a non convex optimization, is sensitive to the initialization. In the above code I used random initialization - randomly choosing samples form data to be the initial centroids. There are better approaches out there (See [K-Means++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means%2B%2B) as an example for a more robust initialization).

Comment: Your answer is real good but you haven't stated where my implementation went wrong. To be clear, the code I wrote for a faster computation produced results but they were inaccurate. (That's why I added a speculation at the end of my answer). Please include that as well, thank you.

Comment: I don't know what's `K` and `n` in your code. I gave you the code to do it in 3rd dimension correctly. Also, it is better to keep the distance matrix as a variable. It is useful for other parts of the K-Means algorithm.

Comment: `K` is the number of medians and `n` stands for number of dimensions (no. of columns of **X**)

Comment: Moreover, using `reapmat()` for vecotrization should be last resort. As it creates more memory allocations which is bad for performance. So I'm not sure why you insist on it.

Comment: I added the reason it fails and wrote how to make it work.

Comment: I insisted on it because I am familiar with numpy new axis function which can generate the differences of 2 matrices which maybe of different dimensions. i.e. row of 1st matrix minus all the rows of centroid matrix. To do that on matlab, I replicated my **X** so that the `new-axes` are manually created.

Comment: This is called Implicit Broadcasting. [MATLAB has it as well](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/compatible-array-sizes-for-basic-operations.html). See my code, it utilizes it.